# Searching for word and output 'none' if not found

Tags: bash

I would like to search for word between 'start' and 'end' and output it and if not found, need to output 'none'

```
cat test.txt

start
item#1  item#2
item#4
end

start
item#1  item#3
item#4
end

start
item#1  item#2
item#5
end
```

I tried `awk '/start/,/end/' | egrep -o item#3 || echo "none" test.txt`

the output is as below

```
item#3
```

The wanted output is

```
none
item#3
none
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part is correct: `awk '/start/,/end/'`, it shows the entries between "start" and "end".

Now what you want to do is:

- Replace all non-`#item3` by "none"

Wat you are doing is:

- Only show the `#item3` matches.

This is indeed not working.

Therefore, instead of a `grep` (a filtering mechanism), I'd opt for a `sed "s/.../.../g"` (a replacement mechanism).

Comment: Thanks Dominique, much appreciated but I'm still don't know how to use the sed. because what I need is like to search between start and end and output the match else out 'none'

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
   /start/ {found=1; i=NR; a[i]="none"; next}
   /end/   {found=0;}
   found   {if($0 ~ "item#3"){a[i]="item#3"}}
   END{
      for(i in a) print a[i]
   }
' test.txt

none
item#3
none
```

---

Using variables

```
awk -v m1="start" -v m2="end" -v s="item#3" -v o="none" '
   $1==m1 {found=1; i=NR; a[i]=o; next}
   $1==m2 {found=0;}
   found  { $0 ~ s ? a[i]=s : ""}
   END{
      for(i in a) print a[i]
   }
' test.txt

none
item#3
none
```